# how do i position a div just beside the image in mouseover using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, mouseover

I managed to do a mouse over, using jQuery. wherein I declare a div inside it

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
.attr("r", 30)
.style("stroke", "white")
.style("stroke-width", 4)
.attr("fill", "url(#img)")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    0;

    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", .9)


    div.html(
        "<div id='hover'>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div class='g-hover-card'>" +
        "<img src='" + d.cover + "' alt='' />" +
        "<div class='user-avatar'>" +
        "<img src='" + d.img + "' alt='' />" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='info'>" +
        "<div class='description'>" +
        "<font size='5px'>" + d.name + "</font>" + "<br /><font color='black'>" + d.relationship + "</font>" +

        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='bottom'>" +
        "<br/>" +
        "<a onclick=\"window.open('http://facebook.com/" + d.id + ");\" rel='publisher' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>" + "Follow on Facebook" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>"

    )

})

.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
});
```

so when i hover on the circle the div showed its just that its not positioned beside the circle. its on the upper left of the screen. How can I put it near the circle?

check it here  http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq

Comment: Position the dive relatively to the circle with plain CSS (`position: absolute`). Then, show it on hover.

Comment: can u provide a fiddle link for dis, so that we can give precise solutions

Comment: check this out [jsfiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/

Comment: I also like that the div won't disappear until I hover the mouse on it so that I can still click the link in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have rewritten your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/3/). I hope this will help you to resolve the issue:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
.attr("r", 30)
.style("stroke", "white")
.style("stroke-width", 4)
.attr("fill", "url(#img)")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {

    circlePos = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", .9)
        .style("left", (circlePos.left + circlePos.width + window.scrollX) + 'px')
        .style("top", (circlePos.top + window.scrollY) + 'px')
        .style("position", "absolute")


    div.html(
        "<div >" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div>" +
        "<div class='g-hover-card'>" +
        "<img src='" + d.cover + "' alt='' />" +
        "<div class='user-avatar'>" +
        "<img src='" + d.img + "' alt='' />" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='info'>" +
        "<div class='description'>" +
        "<font size='5px'>" + d.name + "</font>" + "<br /><font color='black'>" + d.relationship + "</font>" +

        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='bottom'>" +
        "<br/>" +
        "<a onclick=\"window.open('http://facebook.com/" + d.id + ");\" rel='publisher' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>" + "Follow on Facebook" +
        "</a>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>"

    )

})

.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
});
```

[Code Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3mdszohq/3/show/).

Comment: thanks I had tried this but it still don't work. I managed to make a jsfiddle [jsfiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/

Comment: thanks a lot for fixing my code.. I also had another issue sorry I forgot to add it to my issue. Is it possible that the div won't fade out not until the mouse is not pointed on the circle and also the div? Because there's a link on the div wherein the user can go on that when they click it.

Comment: Please check new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/4/). I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Previous code has issues while mouse Out. It wasn't removed the innerHTML of parent. So I created new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/5/) please check and use.